# Check if indexes of packages are consecutive and then join their data

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, indexing, append

I'm getting packages of data from the accelerometer. Those contain fixed length of x,y,z (10 of each) measurements of accelerations. I would like to make time series from the consecutive packages. When there is a missing package, I finished the previous time series and start making a new one.

Data is in two np.arrays (just to make it more clear). First one contains indexes of packages:

```
share_num = np.array([1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10 ...], dtype=int)
```

Second one contains data linked to the index of package:

```
share_sensor = np.array([[x1_1,y1_1,z1_1,...,x10_1,y10_1,z10_1],
                         [x1_2,y1_2,z1_2,...,x10_2,y10_2,z10_2],
                                  ...             ], dtype=int)
```

Output (in my case it's a list of np.arrays) for this specific example because there are consecutive numbers from 1 to 3:

```
X = [np.array([x1_1,y1_1,z1_1,...,x10_3,y10_3,z10_3]),
     np.array([x1_5,y1_5,z1_5,...,x10_5,y10_5,z10_5]),
     np.array([x1_8,y1_8,z1_8,...,x10_10,y10_10,z10_10]),
                  ...                                ]
```

My try works but I'm sure it can be improved - regarding speed and especially to make it more clear. I'm making list of numpy arrays with different lengths.

```
X = []

for idx, (current_num, current_sensor) in enumerate(zip(share_num, share_sensor)):
        if idx == 0:           
            measurement = current_sensor
        else:
            if current_num - previous_num == 1:
                measurement = np.hstack([measurement, current_sensor])
            else: 
                X.append(measurement)

                measurement = current_sensor               

        previous_num = current_num

    X.append(measurement)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample output of what you want? And I don't understand `share_sensor`, are the values supposed to be repeated every row?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I added what output X is supposed to look like. Values are different in every row (I also added an additional index to emphasize that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a way to do that, with numpy primitives :

```
#random data
share_num=sorted(random.sample(range(20),8))
share_sensors=np.random.rand(8,30)

#find "packets"
splits,=(np.diff(share_num)>1).nonzero()
gp_sensors=np.split(share_sensors,splits+1)

X=[g.ravel() for g in gp_sensors]
```

it's more efficient this way, since no sensor data is copied:

```
In [3]: share_sensors.flags.owndata
Out[3]: True

In [4]: gp_sensors[0].flags.owndata
Out[4]: False

In [5]: X[0].flags.owndata
Out[5]: False
```